# Store and send form data to localStorage and webserver with jQuery mobile and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an app with jQuery mobile and PhoneGap (Android) on Eclipse. I'm testing the app (index.html) with my chrome browser.

I want to build a login-system, so I've two pages: login and registration, both with html forms. Now I want to store the form data from registration in the localStorage (E-Mail and logged in flag) and send the data (E-Mail and Password) also to my node.js webserver (not implemented yet, because don't know how).

I've tried to do this, but it doesn't work. I've opend the registration form in my Browser (Chrome) and called the JavaScript Console (Resources -> Local Storage), but there is no data.

Then I want to show the data in the login page, but that doesn't work too.

That's my code:
http://jsbin.com/IBEgoyIf/2/edit?html,js,output

or here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/matchPassword.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



    <div data-role="page" id="login">


        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="http://foo.com/login.js" method="POST">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="url">E-Mail</label>
                    <input name="uid" id="email" placeholder="" value="" type="email" class="required">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="url">Password</label>
                    <input name="upwd" id="pwd" placeholder="" value="" type="password" class="required">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Login">
            </form>
            <p id="myResults">myResults: </p>

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#registration" data-transition="fade" data-theme="" data-icon="edit">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $('#login').on("pagecreate", function() {

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
            //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // device APIs are available
            //function onDeviceReady() {
                var userEmail = window.localStorage.getItem("localEmail");
                var userFlag = window.localStorage.getItem("localLoggedIn");
                document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML = userEmail;
            //}
            //}
        });
        </script>

    </div>
```

---

```
    <div data-role="page" id="registration">

        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="#" method="post" id="registerForm">

                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required email" minlength="5">
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" minlength="5">
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="password2">Repeat Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="required passmatch" minlength="5">
                </fieldset>

                <input type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Register" onclick="store()">
            </form>
        </div>  


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function store(){
                // Wait for device API libraries to load
                //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                // device APIs are available
                //function onDeviceReady() {
                    var inputEmail = document.getElementById("email");
                    localStorage.setItem("localEmail", inputEmail.value);
                    localStorage.setItem("localLoggedIn", true);
                    window.location="#login";
                //}
            }
        </script>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you try to change localStorage.setItem to window.localStorage.setItem?

Comment: Yes, but that also does not work. It's very strange when I try to submit the registration, the login window shows only myResults. If I go back to the registry, the data is still in there. When I try to submit the registration AGAIN, the data is stored into the local storage and shown at the login page.

Comment: I guess the problem is pagecreate in the JavaScript on the login page. But I don't know how to solve it

Comment: What if you use weinre and inside the console you try to get the value typing the command to print the variable value? I have done that severa times with sucess.